# iPhone calendar EKEvent

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, calendar, ekevent

I am currently trying to create an iPhone calendar app. In order to make sure it syncs with the existing iPhone calendars, I am using the `EKEvent` toolkit.

However, the events I will be storing will have more properties than the ones `EKEvent` allows for- e.g., my events will not just have title, details and the few other categories that are allowed for; they will also have themes, priorities...

Thus, when I load the `EKEventStore` every time my calendar starts up, this information will not be contained in the `EKEvents` that are loaded.

How can I associate this information to the existing `EKEvents` so that whenever my calendar is loaded, these additional properties are also loaded?

I would use the `eventIdentifier` but the iPhone documentation says that "If the calendar of an event changes, its identifier most likely changes as well." If I am reading this correctly, this means that I cannot consistently use `eventIdentifier` to identify an event..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `notes` property and set a string which you can parse later.
Since EKCalendarItem is EKEvent's superclass some of the properties of `EKEvent` are inherited from `EKCalendarItem`. ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html))

However, you can still 'set' notes on an `EKEvent`, even though notes is not a property of `EKEvent` anymore. (go figure)

So, from your question, I might set an integer for each of your additional (custom) properties, like so..

In the view controller code that creates the event:
- set an integer for each of you custom options. (priority, theme, etc.)

int priority = 0;

```
    EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:yourEventStore];

    [newEvent setCalendar:yourCalendar];

    if (priority == 0) {
        newEvent.notes = @"0"
    }

    newEvent.title = @"YourTitle";
    newEvent.startDate = yourStartDate;
    newEvent.endDate = yourEndDate;

    [youreventStore saveEvent:newEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
```

Then if you want to check/convert the custom property, just check the notes of the event whenever you fetch them either using `characterAtIndex` or make a subString from the notes and compare that to another string.

Comment: You say EKCalendarItem is EKEvent's superclass, but I can't find that documented anywhere.  (The linked document lists EKObject.)  Where is it documented?